# Return value from a select within an insert

Tags: java, mysql

I have a table whose rows have pseudo random unique IDs. I do so by selecting the first unused entry from a table of random permutation.

```
INSERT INTO test.Eyes (EyeId, DeviceId, DeviceName)
SELECT RandomNumber, "abcd", "efgh" 
FROM test.RandomPermutation
WHERE RandomNumber NOT IN 
(SELECT EyeId FROM test.Eyes) LIMIT 1;
```

(Obviously "abcd" and "efgh" are placeholders here).

It works fine, the row is inserted as it should. I don't want it to be two different calls to prevent race condition. My problem is that I also want to return this random ID (the value of `EyeId`) in Java. There's the function `getGeneratedKeys`, but it only returns auto increment value. Is there a way to return a value got from a select?

Comment: Can you have a normal auto increment id as well? Insert based on that and generating your random id. Then use getGeneratedKeys to get the auto increment id, and from that return the assigned random id?

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that works. I hoped it'll be possible with a single call to the DB, but I suppose one more won't kill it. However, I'm afraid it'll have impact on the time it'd take to query a row based on the random number.

Comment: The query based on a known random id should still be very quick (assuming the random id column is set up as a unique key).